# Get bean property getter or setter by reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, javabeans

Suppose I have a handle on an object of type , and I'm told by configuration that it has a bean property of type `int` with the name `age`.  How can I retrieve the getter for this document?

Is there a better way than prepending "get" and capitalizing the "a" in `age`, and looking for a method of that name via reflection?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Take a look at [`java.beans.Introspector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html).  This class allows you to get the list of properties on a class.

If you know property name you can call

```
Method getter = new PropertyDescriptor(propertyName, beanClass).getReadMethod();
```

See Also:

- [`java.beans.PropertyDescriptor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html)
- [`java.lang.reflect.Method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html)